# Kotlin to Java conversion not working in Android studio Electric Eel. Is there another method to convert?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

[conversion functions are unavailable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ME2hK.png)

I accidentally created a project in Kotlin, while creating an activity I noticed that my class is not in Java, I tried to use conversion techniques but none of them are available(show Kotlin bytecode & decompile to Java.
Is there another way to convert the project to Java?

Comment: If you just created the project, the simplest solution would be to delete the old project and create it again, this time choosing Java.

Comment: going along with what @CommonsWare said, just make it again in Java. Decompiling the kotlin to java will just give you a bunch of unreadable decompiled code that will be hard to work with.

Comment: Converting Kotlin to Java is much harder than the other way around, and not well supported.

Comment: But imagine how unfortunate it would be for someone who has a big project in Kotlin but because those functions are unavailable they are forced to translate all that code by hand  lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's definitely some IDEs (like IntelliJ) that have built-in tools that might be able to decompile Kotlin code into Java, but they're probably likely to produce some pretty verbose Java code than what you might write by hand.

Sorry to say that depending on how complicated your initial code is, you may be better off trying to translate the Kotlin code to Java by hand. Generally, Java has more boilerplate and redundancy in the language than Kotlin.

For example, Kotlin will let you do something like:

```
val myString = "yo"
val myInt = 1
```

Where Java will want you to explicitly type variables like

```
String myString = "yo"
int myInt = 1
```

Functions also differ.
Kotlin uses `fun` to define functions. It has the name of the parameter first followed by the type and then has the return type between the method params and the body.

```
// functions that return void can omit the void keyword
fun myVoidFunction() {
    println("oh hello!")
}

fun myFunctionReturnsAString(someName: String): String {
    return ("oh hi, $someName!")
}
```

Java has the return type at the start of the function and then uses the format of `Type parameter` (reverse of Kotlin)

```
public void myVoidFunction() {
    System.out.println("oh hello!");
}

public String myFunctionReturnsAString(String param) {
    return (param);
}
```

If your code is pretty simple, that might be enough to get you unstuck. If it's more complicated, you might try doing the decompile to Java from something like the community version of IntelliJ and then hand clean it up afterwards. This page has a section describing how to use IntelliJ to go from Kotlin -> Java

https://www.baeldung.com/kotlin/convert-to-java

Definitely don't trust it to do everything cleanly though. You'll likely still need to go through what it creates in Java and fix up code and make it production ready. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you so much for such detailed answer!